# Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::methodblock

Tags: magento-1.7, error, methods

here is a block file:

```
<?php
class webhive_ManageUrl_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{   
 public function methodblock()
 {
     return 'informations about my block !!' ;
 }
}
```

view file:

```
<?php
    echo $this->methodblock();
?>
```

ERROR:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:64:"Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::methodblock(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:3006:"#0       C:\wamp\www\majento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\manageurl\afficher.phtm     l(2): Varien_Object->__call('methodblock', Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\manageurl\afficher.phtml(2): Mage_Core_Block_Template->methodblock()
#2 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\wamp\\www\\maj...')
#3 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\\defau...')
#4 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#10 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#11 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\wamp\\www\\maj...')
#12 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\\defau...')
#13 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919):  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#18 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\local\webhive\ManageUrl\controllers\Adminhtml\MyformController.php(7): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#19 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): webhive_ManageUrl_Adminhtml_MyformController->indexAction()
#20 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#21 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 C:\wamp\www\majento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 C:\wamp\www\majento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#25  {main}";s:3:"url";s:89:"/majento/index.php/manageurl/adminhtml_myform/index/key/ba22d950a33858b1bb8a1e59938a850b/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/majento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: have you define block type in layout file

Comment: Try echo get_class ($this) to see what class it is you're loading

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR  and Mattew Haworth Thanks...
I changed : <block type="manageurl/monblock"
and it works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your layout file I bet it looks something like this

```
<block type="core/template" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
```

It should be

```
<block type="manageurl/monblock" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
```

and you your config.xml you should have this under the `<global>` tag

```
<blocks>
     <manageurl>
        <class>Webhive_ManageUrl_Block</class>
     </manageurl>
</blocks>
```

Comment: Thanks @Marius:
Working Now:
I changed: <block type="manageurl/monblock"

Comment: @Arslantabassum Welcome to SE.  if an answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted. This way it will serve for future readers.

Comment: ok.............................